# How to modify xslt stylesheet using java?

Tags: java

I want to modify some element values like font size,color in xslt through java.
I tried with following java code

```
File xslFile = new File("D:/header.xsl");
     System.out.println(xslFile.getPath());
     javax.xml.transform.Source xsltSource = new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(xslFile); 
     javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory transformerFactory = javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance();
     javax.xml.transform.Transformer xsltTransformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(xsltSource);
     xsltTransformer.setParameter("clr", "red");
```

The java code building successfully but the value is not reflecting into xsl stylesheet.

Comment: Have a look at [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Using parameter passing this way does not change the original stylesheet, just the in memory representation of it. But, assuming that you have a

```
<xsl:parameter name="clr">blue</xsl:parameter>
```

declaration at the top level of your stylesheet, your code would set the value of that parameter to `red`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried this but still it is not working.

Comment: We need more details. Show us (relevant parts of) your style sheet, your input XML document and the expected result.